# @Scheduled Tasks keep JVM hanging when standalone program wants to exit, JVM needs to be killed

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jvm, scheduled-tasks

i opened this bug in the spring bug tracker. would be cool if some clever people here can already help me

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9341

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set "true" on daemon property for the scheduler - eg

```
<!-- task scheduling for @Scheduled annotation -->
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="1" />

<bean id="myScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
    <property name="poolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="myScheduler-"/>
    <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="false" />
    <property name="daemon" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks. this is also the solution proposed in the original ticket.

Comment: If you do this, your tasks might be terminated non-gracefully. So, you should make sure to call `registerShutdownHook()` on your `AbstractApplicationContext` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having your `@Scheduled` bean implement `DisposableBean` (so it can be informed when the Spring context is shutting down) and explicitly closing the context in your `main()` method?

Conceptually, I don't see how the code posted can work like you expect. Spring needs to launch new threads to run your `@Scheduled` task at the time/rate you configure, which means that when the code in your `main()` method exits, there are non-daemon threads still running in the JVM. If you don't tell Spring to shut these threads down, then how will they be terminated?

edit: to be clear, I think the solution is to explicitly call `close()` on your `ApplicationContext`. Otherwise Spring does not have a way to tell the executor service running your scheduled tasks to shut itself down. A JVM shutdown hook will not be invoked when `main()` exits since non-daemon threads are still running.

Comment: thanks for your comment. implementing "DisposableBean" does not solve the problem - as this code will never be executed (the tasks just keeps running).

according to the spring doc it should be sufficient to register the shutdown hook and not to call ctx.close() explicitly.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-shutdown

Comment: A shutdown hook is never going to be invoked in your case though since the thread running the @Scheduled bean is still running. From the JVM docs for `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()` - "The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events: 1) The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked...". You'll need to find a way to tell Spring to shutdown the thread managing the Scheduled task.

Comment: I haven't used this in Spring 3.1, but in 3.0 (which didn't have annotation support), it looks like @Scheduled beans could be setup by adding a `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which would register the @Scheduled beans with a `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`. This BeanPostProcessor relied on receiving the `destroy()` message of `DisposableBean` in order to be able to shutdown the executor service to stop processing of future @Scheduled tasks. I assume you need to do the same thing in 3.1 - make sure you explicitly close your ApplicationContext so that Spring can shut down the task executor.

Comment: to be clear - you don't need for the @Scheduled class to implement `DisposableBean` - but you *do* need to call ApplicationContext.close().

Comment: but why doesn't the documentation under 3.6.1.6 state this? it just tells me that? shouldn't these be deamon threads that do not prevent the jvm from shutting down?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but if the executor service created daemon threads by default, then your task might be abruptly terminated when it comes time for the JVM to shut down, without a chance to properly finish it's work or cleanup it's resources. You can customize this behavior of the executor service by supplying a custom ThreadFactory; to do so with Spring would require you to configure a bunch of classes from the default behavior. I can't speak to the language of the Spring docs, but it seems to just be about how to register a shutdown hook, not *when* that shutdown hook will be invoked.

Comment: Why do you have an aversion to just calling `context.close()`?

Comment: i don't have an aversion. just curious if this a bug or intended.

Comment: This is also the answer given on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17992

If you make your instance that manages the ApplicationContext extend `AutoCloseable`, then in its close method you can call through to `close()` on the application context to shut it down gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution using Java config

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler daemonTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    taskScheduler.setDaemon(false);
    taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("daemon");
    taskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    return taskScheduler;
}
```

or if you want to really get into the details, the config class can be like this

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
```

One thing is not supported though is to be able to use multiple TaskSchedulers within a single application. I opened a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16271) for that