# Tomcat memory leak warning on HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, spring, httpurlconnection, tomcat8, memory-leak-detector

I have the following warning in Tomcat 8.5 I'm not sure I can ignore

```
WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [AppName] appears to have started a thread named [pool-20-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
```

It happens on `connect` in the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(MY_URL);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) con;
http.setRequestMethod("POST");
http.setDoOutput(true);
http.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(out.length);
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
http.connect();
try (OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream()) {
    os.write(out);
}
```

Should I add a finally with closing the `InputStream`:

```
http.getInputStream().close();
```

Or this code should be upgraded/converted to use `URIBuilder` and `HttpHost`?

**EDIT**
The code executed every X seconds using Spring's `@Scheduled`

Comment: You should `disconnect` the `URLConnection` when you are done.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm sending every few seconds the request, Isn't `disconnect` prevent reuse connection?

Comment: You aren't reusing anything here, you are opening a connection each time you need one.

Comment: Can you please post the entire stack trace? Also your exception could be caused by code run in a non-manged thread, are you doing some manual thread setup e.g. custom `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki next line is `http.connect();` shown in code, about threads, I'm just using Spring's `@Scheduled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `@Scheduled` within Tomcat to spawn threads. You must ensure that these threads will finish when the `ServletContext` is destroyed e.g. WAR being undeployed, Tomcat warns you about this. The HTTP request code is unrelated as `URLConnection` doesn't start new threads to perform the request.

One way to make Tomcat happy is to use daemon threads, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25127077/1602555). This can be done with custom `taskScheduler` bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class TaskConfiguration {

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
  public Executor taskScheduler() {
    return Executors.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4,
        new ThreadFactory() {
          public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
          }
        });
  }

}
```

Comment: @user7294900 the code looks fine, `HttpURLConnection.disconnect()` is not guaranteed to have desired side effects as per method javadoc. You might want to dig into JVM to understand HTTP connection KeepAlive semantics.

Comment: I found also spring related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300403/scheduled-tasks-keep-jvm-hanging-when-standalone-program-wants-to-exit-jvm-nee